# PDE Similarity Solutions Boundary Value Problem and Solution: Explanation of Steps Requested

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, change-of-variable, dimensional-analysis

I have the following similarity solutions problem and solution:

> **Problem**
>
> $u_t = ku_{xx}$ for all $x > 0$, with $u_x (0, t) = 1$, $u(x, t) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, and $u(x, 0) = 0$ for $x > 0$.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Introducing $u′ = \dfrac{u}{u_0}$, $t′ = \dfrac{t}{t_0}$ and $x′ = \dfrac{x}{x_0}$, we will reduce the original PDE to
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial{u′}}{\partial{t′}} = \dfrac{\partial^2{u'}}{\partial{x'}^2}$$
>
> when choosing $x^2_0 = k t_0$.
>
> The boundary condition $u_x(0, t) = 1$ will make us choose $x_0 = u_0$ so that $u'_{x'} (0, t') = 1$.
>
> Choosing $t_0 = t$ we have
>
> $$\sqrt{kt}u' \left( \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{kt}}, 1 \right) = \sqrt{kt} f(\eta), \eta = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{kt}}$$
>
> The PDE will reduce to the ODE
>
> $$f''(\eta) + \dfrac{\eta}{2}f'(\eta) − \dfrac{1}{2}f(\eta) = 0$$
>
> subject to $f'(0) = 0$ and $f(\eta) \to 0$ as $\eta \to \infty$.

I was told that, despite how this problem was posed, my instructor would provide us with the change of variables $u′ = \dfrac{u}{u_0}$, $t′ = \dfrac{t}{t_0}$ and $x′ = \dfrac{x}{x_0}$.

However, I'm struggling to understand the reasoning behind each of the steps taken in the solution. For all of these steps, I find myself asking "Why was this step taken/How did they know to take this step?". Can someone please take the time to annotate this solution with explanations of each step, so that I can understand this type of problem and be able to do it myself in the future? In other words, please walk me through the process, explaining why each step was taken.

For instance, why will the boundary condition $u_x(0, t) = 1$ make us choose $x_0 = u_0$? Where did $u'_{x'} (0, t') = 1$ come from?

And so on for the rest of the solution ...

I would really appreciate it if someone could please take the time to do this.

Comment: [I found these notes to be quite useful](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahhwi/LTCC/sectionB-similarity.pdf).

Comment: @Mattos Hi Mattos. Can you please check over the solution and comment on whether it is correct? As I said, I have a suspicion that there are errors. Thanks for the notes. I will read over them. Do you, by any chance, have any textbook recommendations for similarity solutions problems? I've struggled to find such a textbook.

Comment: @Mattos I don't find those notes helpful at all. The example seems too far detached from this one to give any meaningful insight to me.

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to get a $t_{0}$ in the denominator in your first question. Using your approach, we have $$u(x,t) = u_{0}u'(x_{0}x', t_{0}t')$$ and so \begin{align} u_{t}&=u_{0}u'_{t} \\ &=u_{0}u'_{t'}t'_{t} \\ &=\frac{u_{0}}{t_{0}}u'_{t'} \end{align} Similarly, \begin{align} u_{x}&=u_{0}u'_{x} \\ &=u_{0}u'_{x'} x'_{x} \\ &=\frac{u_{0}}{x_{0}}u'_{x'} \\ \implies u_{xx}&=\frac{u_{0}}{x^{2}_{0}}u'_{x'x'} \end{align} Putting together yields $$\frac{u_{0}}{t_{0}} u'_{t'} = k \frac{u_{0}}{x^{2}_{0}} u'_{x'x'}$$ and hence we require $x^{2}_{0} = k t_{0}^{2}$. So the notes are correct.

Comment: @Mattos Yes! I just realised that I made the error as you were typing this. Thanks for the clarification. Can you please comment on where the other stuff like 2. comes from?

Comment: Use the derivation in my previous comment that shows $u_{x}=\frac{u_{0}}{x_{0}}u'_{x'}$. Then set $x = x_{0}x' = 0$.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks, I think I managed to understand this part. Can you please clarify where $f''(\eta) + \dfrac{\eta}{2}f'(\eta) − \dfrac{1}{2}f(\eta) = 0$ comes from?

Comment: Compute $$u'_{t} = f_{t} = \frac{df}{d \eta} \frac{d \eta}{dt} = \dots$$ Similarly for $u'_{xx}$.

Comment: @Mattos Above, I think you meant to write that we require $x^{2}_{0} = k t_{0}$?

Comment: @Mattos How did they get $\sqrt{kt}u' \left( \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{kt}}, 1 \right) = \sqrt{kt} f(\eta), \eta = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{kt}}$? We have $u(x,t) = u_{0}u'(x_{0}x', t_{0}t')$, so we get $u(x,t) = u_{0}u' \left( \sqrt{kt_0} \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{kt_0}}, t_{0} \dfrac{t}{t_0} \right)$. I don't see where the $ \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{kt}}$ and $1$ come from?

Comment: Yes, I meant $x_{0}^{2} = kt$. Using the scalings, you have $$t' = \frac{t}{t_{0}} = \frac{t}{t} = 1$$ Similarly, you have $$x' = \frac{x}{x_{0}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{kt}}$$ and so $$u'(x', t') = u'\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{kt}}, 1\right)$$

Comment: @Mattos But what is the reasoning behind why we can now write it as $u'(x', t')$ instead of $u_{0}u'(x_{0}x', t_{0}t')$, which is what we had before? Can we simply ignore the $x_0$ and $t_0$ since they are just scaling factors? Not sure what the reasoning behind this change is.

Comment: I have a very similar question. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone would take a look :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140776/similarity-solution-method-changing-the-boundary-conditions